# The mobile navbar menu doesn't close after it's clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

When I click on the mobile navbar, it simply doesn't close when an item is clicked on, it only goes to the section where that item is but the navbar is still on:

here is the HTML for the header:

```
  <header id="header" class="fixed-top d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">

      <h1 class="logo me-auto"><a href="#"><a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="elsahel">Logo</a></a></h1>
      <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
      <!-- <a href="index.html" class="logo me-auto"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>-->

      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">

        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#clients">Our Suppliers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Our Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#customers">Clients</a></li>
          <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>


        <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>

        <a href="index2.html" class="getstarted">Spanish</a>


      </nav><!-- .navbar -->

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->
```

CSS navbar code:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Navigation Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
* Desktop Navigation 
*/
.navbar {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar li {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar a,
.navbar a:focus {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 30px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #556270;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar a i,
.navbar a:focus i {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.navbar .active,
.navbar .active:focus,
.navbar li:hover>a {
  color: #0609c9;
}

.navbar .getstarted,
.navbar .getstarted:focus {
  background: #2600ce;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar .getstarted:hover,
.navbar .getstarted:focus:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #050aac;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 14px;
  top: calc(100% + 30px);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul li {
  min-width: 200px;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul a i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul a:hover,
.navbar .dropdown ul .active:hover,
.navbar .dropdown ul li:hover>a {
  color: #1b07c7;
}

.navbar .dropdown:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}

.navbar .dropdown .dropdown ul {
  top: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 30px);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.navbar .dropdown .dropdown:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}

@media (max-width: 1366px) {
  .navbar .dropdown .dropdown ul {
    left: -90%;
  }

  .navbar .dropdown .dropdown:hover>ul {
    left: -100%;
  }
}

/**
* Mobile Navigation 
*/
.mobile-nav-toggle {
  color: #556270;
  font-size: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  line-height: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle.bi-x {
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .mobile-nav-toggle {
    display: block;
  }

  .navbar ul {
    display: none;
  }
}


.navbar-mobile {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(63, 73, 83, 0.9);
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-mobile .mobile-nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

.navbar-mobile ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar-mobile a,
.navbar-mobile a:focus {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #556270;
}

.navbar-mobile a:hover,
.navbar-mobile .active,
.navbar-mobile li:hover>a {
  color: #0e0bd8;
}

.navbar-mobile .getstarted,
.navbar-mobile .getstarted:focus {
  margin: 15px;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul li {
  min-width: 200px;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul a i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul a:hover,
.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul .active:hover,
.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul li:hover>a {
  color: #2d17f3;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown>.dropdown-active {
  display: block;
}
```

The whole javascript code:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  /**
   * Easy selector helper function
   */
  const select = (el, all = false) => {
    el = el.trim()
    if (all) {
      return [...document.querySelectorAll(el)]
    } else {
      return document.querySelector(el)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Easy event listener function
   */
  const on = (type, el, listener, all = false) => {
    let selectEl = select(el, all)
    if (selectEl) {
      if (all) {
        selectEl.forEach(e => e.addEventListener(type, listener))
      } else {
        selectEl.addEventListener(type, listener)
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Easy on scroll event listener 
   */
  const onscroll = (el, listener) => {
    el.addEventListener('scroll', listener)
  }

  /**
   * Toggle .header-scrolled class to #header when page is scrolled
   */
  let selectHeader = select('#header')
  if (selectHeader) {
    const headerScrolled = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        selectHeader.classList.add('header-scrolled')
      } else {
        selectHeader.classList.remove('header-scrolled')
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', headerScrolled)
    onscroll(document, headerScrolled)
  }

  /**
   * Back to top button
   */
  let backtotop = select('.back-to-top')
  if (backtotop) {
    const toggleBacktotop = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        backtotop.classList.add('active')
      } else {
        backtotop.classList.remove('active')
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', toggleBacktotop)
    onscroll(document, toggleBacktotop)
  }


  /**
   * Hero carousel indicators
   */
  let heroCarouselIndicators = select("#hero-carousel-indicators")
  let heroCarouselItems = select('#heroCarousel .carousel-item', true)

  heroCarouselItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    (index === 0) ?
    heroCarouselIndicators.innerHTML += "<li data-bs-target='#heroCarousel' data-bs-slide-to='" + index + "' class='active'></li>":
      heroCarouselIndicators.innerHTML += "<li data-bs-target='#heroCarousel' data-bs-slide-to='" + index + "'></li>"
  });

  /**
   * Porfolio isotope and filter
   */
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let portfolioContainer = select('.portfolio-container');
    if (portfolioContainer) {
      let portfolioIsotope = new Isotope(portfolioContainer, {
        itemSelector: '.portfolio-item'
      });

      let portfolioFilters = select('#portfolio-flters li', true);

      on('click', '#portfolio-flters li', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        portfolioFilters.forEach(function(el) {
          el.classList.remove('filter-active');
        });
        this.classList.add('filter-active');

        portfolioIsotope.arrange({
          filter: this.getAttribute('data-filter')
        });
      }, true);
    }

  });

  /**
   * Initiate portfolio lightbox 
   */
  const portfolioLightbox = GLightbox({
    selector: '.portfolio-lightbox'
  });

  /**
   * Portfolio details slider
   */
  new Swiper('.portfolio-details-slider', {
    speed: 400,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 5000,
      disableOnInteraction: false
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      type: 'bullets',
      clickable: true
    }
  });

  /**
   * Initiate portfolio details lightbox 
   */
  const portfolioDetailsLightbox = GLightbox({
    selector: '.portfolio-details-lightbox',
    width: '90%',
    height: '90vh'
  });

  /**
   * Skills animation
   */
  let skilsContent = select('.skills-content');
  if (skilsContent) {
    new Waypoint({
      element: skilsContent,
      offset: '80%',
      handler: function(direction) {
        let progress = select('.progress .progress-bar', true);
        progress.forEach((el) => {
          el.style.width = el.getAttribute('aria-valuenow') + '%'
        });
      }
    })
  }

})()
```

It seems that the code doesn't include to close the mobile navbar when clicked on.
I have tried several code from stackoverflow but they don't seem to work.

I have tried to add a code from ChatGPT answers, it told me that I need to change the behavior of on and select functions and removed them and used normal selectQuery methods but they didn't work. tried a couple of answers from Stackoverflow, but they don't also seem to work.

Comment: Keep ChatGPT prompting simple. It does better with vanilla Javascript/HTML/CSS. Based off a quick look that's not how I'd do it. Regenerate your answer and try again?

Comment: give me an example on how to give him the question or the code?
because I'm reaching a deadend, I tried multiple times to give a question to ChatGPT but it seems to be giving almost the same answer.

Like, one time, I have asked the question, how to add the close functionality on this code for the mobile navbar when an item is clicked.

Comment: Hello, I would like a navigation bar that's responsive to smaller resolutions, the navigation should contain a logo that's placed on the left side and a few drop-down buttons on the far right. Keep this as simple as possible and separate the HTML/JavaScript/CSS. If you can please add a touch of style to this, I want hover/active cool stuff. Please avoid doing this in anything but vanilla java script; keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see bootstrap classes, then why you need to write custom js..Use the bootstrap navbar and it automatically will work. Sometimes it happen if its not able to locate js..
make sure:

1. If you are using CDN the add the js link as well.
2. If you are adding bootstrap via local folder, then make sure the path are correct.